# The Review System: Why don't I get credit for a rejected edit if it gets approved?

Tags: discussion, review

We've all been here before; a suggested edit comes up and it just doesn't pass your muster.  It's too minor.  They change a tag to something that you don't think goes with the question.  Maybe you don't feel that what they fixed needed to be fixed at all.  So you reject it.

Then you get the dreaded "red box" saying it was already approved.  **Darn it!**

So, you look at your review number, and it hasn't increased.  You reviewed the question, but you don't get credit for it.  Yet, had you just stamped it as "Approved", you would have gotten credit!

I'm just curious about the reasoning behind this.  Doesn't this, to some extent, encourage quickly approving edits?  Shouldn't we get credit for taking the time to review the edit?

Comment: Nope, your base assumption is wrong. If you would have clicked "Approve" it would just skip silently to the next item and the reviews count would not increase as well. The only problem is that we don't get live indication when the review is completed thus whatever we choose will be ignored. (except Improve)

Comment: I don't think you get credit for edits you approve that ultimately get rejected either, so just clicking "Approve" isn't foolproof.

Comment: So anything we review that doesn't get taken into final consideration is ignored?  Doesn't that encourage FGitW-type behavior?

Comment: How does being the FGitW help you make the right decision? I would think it would encourage more careful consideration.

Comment: Well, if you take too long, the edit (or whatever review type you're looking at) could already be approved or rejected and you don't get credit for your review.

Comment: Yes, that last part is a big problem for me lately. (And I have the magic override!) I can’t take the time to type in an Other message explaining why an edit is bad anymore; it’ll be approved.

Comment: Just focus on improving the site by taking the appropriate review actions for any posts shown to you.  You're focusing *way* too much on the score.